# check datetime value is in DateTimeRangeInput in conda panel

Tags: python, conda, bokeh, panel, hvplot

I'm trying to build a conda panel that can see values based on [DatetimeRangeInput](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/DatetimeRangeInput.html) slider

so I created dataframe like this

```
data = {'name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'open_time': [dt.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 21, 0), dt.datetime(2021, 7, 2, 11, 0), dt.datetime(2021, 7, 3, 3, 0),dt.datetime(2021, 7, 3, 2, 0) ],
        'count':[27, 24, 22, 32],
        'size':[34, 56,67,78]
       }

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_sample
```

so the output like this

```
   name open_time          count size
0   A   2021-07-01 21:00:00 27   34
1   B   2021-07-02 11:00:00 24   56
2   C   2021-07-03 03:00:00 22   67
3   D   2021-07-03 02:00:00 32   78
```

then added y axis options in this way

```
yaxis_sample = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(
    name='Y axis', 
    options=['count', 'size'],
    button_type='success'
)
```

widget created like this

```
date_range = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(
    name='Date Range',
    start=dt.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 00, 00, 00), end=dt.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 00, 00, 00),
    value=(dt.datetime(2021, 7, 2, 00, 00, 00), dt.datetime(2021, 7, 4, 00, 00, 00)),
)

date_range
```

[image]
then I'm struggling to combine pipeline and widget, in this section

```
names = ['A', 'B','C', 'D']

sample_pipeline = (
    df[
        (date_range.align(df_sample.open_time)) &
        (df_sample.name.isin(names))
    ]
    .groupby(['name', 'open_time'])[yaxis_sample].mean()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='open_time')  
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

how to check `df_sample.open_time` is in the range of `date_range.value` ?

I've tried following

Attempt 1

```
names = ['A', 'B','C', 'D']

sample_pipeline = (
    df[
        (df_sample.open_time >= date_range.param.value_start) & (df_sample.open_time <= date_range.param.value_end) &
        (df_sample.name.isin(names))
    ]
    .groupby(['name', 'open_time'])[yaxis_sample].mean()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='open_time')  
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

> TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Date

Attempt 2

```
names = ['A', 'B','C', 'D']

sample_pipeline = (
    df[
        (df_sample.open_time >= date_range.start) & (df_sample.open_time <= date_range.end) &
        (df_sample.name.isin(names))
    ]
    .groupby(['name', 'open_time'])[yaxis_sample].mean()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='open_time')  
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: What is "*a conda panel*"?

Comment: @merv https://anaconda.org/anaconda/panel this is the one https://panel.holoviz.org/

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear in your post, but something you have to do is instantiate an interactive dataframe with `df.interactive()`, `.interactive` being a dataframe accessor that is registered by hvPlot to on Pandas dataframes when importign `hvplot.pandas`.

Then indeed you were right in your first attempt, the trick with the date ranges is to rely on the *Parameter* `value_start` and `value_end`.

```py
import datetime as dt
import hvplot.pandas
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn

# Data init
data = {'name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'open_time': [dt.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 21, 0), dt.datetime(2021, 7, 2, 11, 0), dt.datetime(2021, 7, 3, 3, 0),dt.datetime(2021, 7, 3, 2, 0) ],
        'count':[27, 24, 22, 32],
        'size':[34, 56,67,78]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

names = ['A', 'B','C', 'D']

# Create an interactive dataframe
dfi = df.interactive()

# Create the widgets that will drive the pipeline

date_range = pn.widgets.DateRangeSlider(
    name='Date Range',
    start=dt.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 00, 00, 00), end=dt.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 00, 00, 00),
    value=(dt.datetime(2021, 7, 2, 00, 00, 00), dt.datetime(2021, 7, 4, 00, 00, 00)),
)
yaxis_sample = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(
    name='Y axis', 
    options=['count', 'size'],
    button_type='success'
)

# Create the pipeline
sample_pipeline = (
    dfi[
        (dfi.open_time >= date_range.param.value_start) & (dfi.open_time <= date_range.param.value_end) &
        (dfi.name.isin(names))
    ]
    .groupby(['name', 'open_time'])[yaxis_sample].mean()
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='open_time')  
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
sample_pipeline
```

[image]